# Determine the user input is either a vowel or not using switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

```
public class vowel { 
     private static int ch;    
     public static void main(String[]args){     
        char vowel;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);     
        System.out.println("Enter alphabet:" );     
        vowel=sc.next().charAt(0);

    switch (ch){    
        case 'a':     
        case 'A':     
        case 'e':     
        case 'E':     
        case 'i':     
        case 'I':     
        case 'o':     
        case 'O':     
        case 'u':     
        case 'U':    
           System.out.println("This is a Vowel:"+ vowel);
           break;
        default:
           System.out.println("This is not a Vowel:"+ vowel);
           break;

        }
    } 
}
```

the problem is that no matter what letter i enter, it will always have an outcome of saying 'This is not a Vowel' although it is.

Comment: `switch {` is invalid.  What are you switching on?

Comment: Could you post code that compiles?

Comment: @0x499602D2 it is java

Comment: The switch should have an expression in it... like `switch (vowel)`

Comment: @user3294763 You're switching on `ch`, not `vowel`. Get rid of this `ch` variable and do `switch (vowel){`

Comment: @SJuan76 sorry, i tried but the problem is that when any letter is entered by the user, it still says that 'This is not a Vowel' even when it is, sorry guys im a first year student

Comment: Put capital `V` in your class name: `Vowel`.  Otherwise it works.

Comment: check this [C# program to check whether a input character is vowel or not using switch statement](http://www.msccomputerscience.com/2014/04/c-program-to-check-whether-input.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `vowel` is the letter you are looking at, you need to add that to your switch statement. The first code you provided didn't know what variable you were using for comparison.

```
switch(vowel){ //You need something here.
    case 'a':     
    case 'A':
    // continue with other vowels 
        System.out.println("This is a Vowel:"+ vowel);
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("This is not a Vowel:"+ vowel);
        break;
}
```

Don't switch on `ch`, you aren't even using that in the code you provided. Unless you are using that somewhere else in your code, you can remove it completely.

---

**EDIT**

If you want to look at a whole string and check each char for whether or not it is a vowel try something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);     
    System.out.print("Enter a word: " ); //Better prompt IMO
    String str = sc.next(); //Get the whole string
    char[] myChar = str.toCharArray(); //Turn the string into an array of char

    for (char c : myChar) { //For every char in the array
        switch (c) { //Check if it is a vowel or not
            case 'a':     
            case 'A':     
            case 'e':     
            case 'E':     
            case 'i':     
            case 'I':     
            case 'o':     
            case 'O':     
            case 'u':     
            case 'U':    
                System.out.println(c + " - Vowel"); //Easier for me to read
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println(c);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i just tried, but although it runs, if i enter the letter 'a' when running the program, it only displays 'this is not a Vowel: A'

Comment: @user3294763 You entered 'a' but it prints _"'this is not a Vowel: **A**' "_ ? Are you sure that you are running the program you posted?

Comment: @user3294763 I have tested the code that I posted in my edit many times and it works correctly. If you still have problems tell me what they are.

Comment: it works now thanks guys! i forgot to change a variable1